# DunitX, how to run only one test?

Tags: delphi, dunit, dunitx

Everytime I run my DUnitX project, it's ran all tests. Is their a simple way to make it run only one test (The test I m working on for example)? Is it possible specify the test to run in the command line?

Comment: Seems DUnitX doesn't have a GUI runner even if it is mentioned in the help on Embarcadero's site.  Most appear to use [TestInsite](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/testinsight/wiki/Home) to run tests from the IDE since it supports DUnitX.

Comment: Is this dunit or dunitx, there seems to be some confusion in the title  question anf tags

Comment: If it is Dunitx, the documentation (perhaps you didn't find it yet) shows a GUI runner which allows selective running. And there are other runners around. What runner are you using?

Comment: Delphi adds to the confusion - you select DUnit under manage platforms and it installs DUnitX. The Delphi online help mentions a GUI runner but the GIT for DUnitX say that is a planned feature but it is crossed out and it says : Use TestInsight. Also seems to be TestInsight and TestInsite out there to make it even more confusing.

Comment: @Brian thanks personally I was thinking that dunit and dunitX it's the same, except that dunitX is more recent and work with firemonkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the options yet but it appears that it has command line options to run one test or multiple tests, or use a file to hold the tests to run.

> All available options:
>
> --options:value or -opt:value - Options File
>
> --hidebanner or -b - Hide the License Banner
>
> --xmlfile:value or -xml:value - XML output file path
>
> --runlist:value or -rl:value - Specify the name of a file which lists the tests to run
>
> --run:value or -r:value - Specify the tests to run, separate by commas
>
> --include:value or -i:value - Specify the categories to include
>
> --exclude:value or -e:value - Specify the categories to exclude
>
> --dontshowignored or -dsi - Don't show ignored tests
>
> --loglevel:value or -l:value - Logging Level - Information, Warning, Error
>
> --exitbehavior:value or -exit:value - Exit behavior - Continue, Pause
>
> --h or -? - Show Usage

[DUnitX command line options](https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX/wiki/Command-line-test-execution)

Answer (score 2):

To the first part of your question:

> Is their a simple way to make it run only one test

DUnitX will skip private methods. So just add a `private` label (i.e. section) on top of all your tests, and leave the one you want to test in a public/published section.

When you're done, remove the private label.